# Print the shortest path between two points in a grid C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra, path-finding

The following code is the shortest path algorithm code I am using: [Algorithm to find the shortest path in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59905657/algorithm-to-find-the-shortest-path-in-a-grid)

```
bool isValid(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grid, int i, int j) {
    if(i < 0 || i >= grid.size() || j < 0 || j >= grid[i].size() || grid[i][j] != 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}

int shortestPathBinaryMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
    if(grid.empty())
        return 0;

    if(grid[0][0] == 1 || grid[grid.size()-1][grid.size()-1] == 1) 
        return -1;

    int m = grid.size(), n = grid[0].size();
    pair<int, int> start = {0,0};
    pair<int, int> end = {m-1, n-1};
    vector<vector<bool>> visited(m, vector<bool>(n, false));
    // no priority queue needed: the graph is not weighted
    vector<std::pair<int,int>> q;
    q.push_back(start);
    visited[start.first][start.second] = true;
    int count = 1;

    while(!q.empty())
    {
        // just iterate the vector and populate a new one
        vector<std::pair<int,int>> q2;
        for(auto const& cur: q) {
            if(cur.first == end.first && cur.second == end.second)
                return count;
            for(auto dir : dirs)
            {
                int x = cur.first, y = cur.second;

                if(isValid(grid, x + dir[0], y + dir[1]))
                    x += dir[0], y += dir[1];

                if(!visited[x][y])
                {
                    visited[x][y] = true;
                    q2.push_back({x,y});
                }
            }
        }
        count++;
        q = q2; // prepare for next iteration
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This algorithm works in terms of that it counts the total number of nodes that the shortest path would go through, however, I would like to print the coordinate of every node it passes through.

Using example 2 from the question page (https://leetcode.com/problems/shortest-path-in-binary-matrix/), the input grid is

[0,0,0]

[1,1,0]

[1,1,0]

The output would be 4 for this question, but I would like to have [0][0]->[1][0]->[2][1]->[2][2] as the result. Any ideas on how to trace the shortest path taken with this code? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Using the Chebyshev distance I see.  I was expecting Manhatten distance.

Comment: I would say dynamic programming with path reconstruction